# How are my PHP cloud storage platform's digital storage conversions? Should there be anything else I should add in?

Tags: php, cloud, storage, cloud-storage

```
//Define size variants for FREE SPACE:
if($freespace == 1){
$formatted_size_free = number_format(round($freespace)) . " byte";
} else if($freespace < 1000){
$formatted_size_free = number_format(round($freespace)) . " bytes";
} else if($freespace < 1000000){
$formatted_size_free = number_format(round($freespace / 1000)) . " KB";
} else if($freespace < 1000000000){
$formatted_size_free = number_format(round($freespace / 1000 / 1000)) . " MB";
} else if($freespace < 1000000000000 || $freespace >= 1000000000000){
$formatted_size_free = number_format(round($freespace / 1000 / 1000 / 1000)) . " GB";
}
```

For anyone interested in the project we're working on (it's practically finished), the platform is https://crumbdrive.com.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually KB, MB, GB are dividing by 1024(2^10). If you divided by 1000(10^3) it make dental error.

Comment: I first considered doing this. But, now I'll consider it even more, since, it is, as you say, an error. But, what's a "dental error"? Thanks!

Comment: Example, following your code above, if you show 1GB = 10^9, but actually 1GB needing 2^30 => dental error is |10^9 - 2 ^30| = 73741824 Byte = 0.0686774254 GB => free space actually  about 0.93 GB

Comment: Oh, okay! I've always heard that my conversions should be like what you've mentioned. When I get back to my desk, I'll redo the conversions. I appreciate your feedback, thank you!